# Gurobi - problem when building constraint (Java)

Tags: java, gurobi

i currently have a problem implementing a contraint.
I have two sets (s1 and s2) of specific GRBVars and try to implement the following contraint:

Sum(s1) - Sum(s2) + constantValue <= someValue

My implementation (modified for easier reading):

```
GRBVar[][] vars;
....

GRBLinExpr expr1 = new GRBLinExpr();
GRBLinExpr expr2 = new GRBLinExpr();

for (Edge edge : s1) {
expr1.addTerm(1.0, vars[edge.getVertex1][edge.getVertex2]);
}

for (Edge edge : s2) {
expr2.addTerm(-1.0, vars[edge.getVertex1][edge.getVertex1]);
}

expr1 += expr2 + 50;
```

The last line expr1 += expr2  + 50 is marked as an error, without any helpful information. According to the documentation (https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/cs_lex.html) it should be possible. What am i missing?
Is there a better way to implement this contraint?

Best regards

Comment: What should `expr1 += expr2 + 50` do? You are trying to use the `+` operator on objects. If you want to add something you have to use the methods of the library provided. You are using java, not a .NET language which supports operator overloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression like `expr1 += expr2 + 50` is only supported by programming languages, which supports operator overloading, as seen in [the documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/cs_lex.html):

> In .NET languages that support operator overloading, you generally build linear expressions using overloaded operators. [...]

The link https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/cs_lex.html is referencing the [.NET API Details](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/cs_net_api_details.html) for the .NET languages. You want to look at https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/java_lex.html which is for the [Java API Details](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/java_api_details.html). There you have the documentation that you can use the `add*()` methods for adding two expressions/terms.

Comment: thanks for answering @Progman. Seems that the filtering option in the documentation does not work as expected :D

Comment: @TheJed It does. The links on the left are filtered on the selection, and via the nodes "Java API Details" -> "GRBLinExpr" you get to the correct documentation.